# Creating a pathname to check a file doesn't exist there / Permission denied error

Tags: linux, bash

Hello from a Linux Bash newbie!

I have a list.txt containing a list of files which I want to copy to a destination($2).  These are unique images but some of them have the same filename.

My plan is to loop through each line in the text file, with the copy to the destination occurring when the file is not there, and a mv rename happening when it is present.

The problem I am having is creating the pathname to check the file against.  In the code below, I am taking the filename only from the pathname, and I want to add that to the destination ($2) with the "/" in between to check the file against.

When I run the program below I get "Permission Denied" at line 9 which is where I try and create the path.

```
for line in $(cat list.txt)
do
file=$[ basename $line ]
path=$[ $2$file ]
echo $path

if [ ! -f $path ];
then
echo cp $line $2
else
echo mv $line.DUPLICATE $2
fi
done
```

I am new to this so appreciate I may be missing something obvious but if anyone can offer any advice it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you paste your script correctly? The `$[ ... ]` don't look correct to me.

Comment: Please use `$(( ))` for arithmetic expansion, as `$[ ]` is deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of bash. And Michal is right, doing arithmetic with a pathname probably isn't a good idea.

Comment: Script has been pasted correctly.  I'm not trying to do arithmetic here, just want to check whether the file I want to copy is already in the destination and react accordingly.

Comment: What about lines 3 and 4? You're definitely using the (deprecated) syntax for arithmetic expansion there. You probably meant to use `$(basename $line)` in line 3 and `"$2$file"` in line 4.

Comment: I'm new to this and not familiar with all the terms and practices yet.

Comment: I've edited my comment above with what you likely intended to do.

Comment: `$(...)` executes the command in the parenthesis and evaluates to whatever the command prints to stdout. Try `foo=$(date); echo $foo)` for example. `$((...))` evaluates to the value of the arithmetic expression in the parenthesis, e.g. `$((2*21))`. `$[...]` does the same, but shouldn't be used anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've given it a try and not getting an error now, however when I echo the path the $file part of the code appears on a new line.

Comment: Could you update your question, please, so we can see what exactly you've changed?

Answer (score 0):

Submitting this since OP is new in BASH scripting no good answer has been posted yet.

```
DESTINATION="$2"

while read -r line; do
  file="${line##*/}"
  path="$2/$file"
  [[ ! -f $path ]] && cp "$line" "$path" || mv "$line" "$path.DUP"
done < list.txt
```

Don't have logic for counting duplicates at present to keep things simple. (Which means code will take care of one dup entry) As an alternative you get `uniq` from `list.txt` beforehand to avoid the duplicate situation.

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava: Your script looks good. Here is a small addition to it to work with several dupes.
It adds a numer to the $path.DUP name

```
UniqueMove()
{
    COUNT=0
    while [ -f "$1" ]
    do 
        (( COUNT++ )) 
        mv -n "$1" "$2$COUNT"
    done
}

while read -r line; do
  file="${line##*/}"
  path="$2/$file"
  [[ ! -f $path ]] && cp "$line" "$path" || UniqueMove "$line" "$path.DUP"
done < list.txt
```